# Meaning of Column properties in SQuirreL SQL

Tags: database-schema, schema-design, squirrel-sql, tablecolumn

I am using SQuilrreL SQL to connect to a local MySQL server, and am looking at the specification of the Columns of some table. At the same time I'm looking at the specification of the same table directly in MySQL (MySQL Workbench), and obviously, the columns' properties are different. For instance, in SQuirelL SQL I have properties like `IS_NULLABLE`, `DECIMAL_DIGITS` and `NUM_PREC_RADIX`, whereas in MySQL I have properties like: `Not Null`, `Auto Increment`, `Zero Fill`.

My question - what are the meanings of all the column properties in SQuirreL SQL? And better yet - how can I map them to MySQL's properties? (some of them are obvious like `IS_NULLABLE` <==> `Not Null`, but most aren't that clear).

I need this since I just used the SQuirreL SQL's plugin CopyDB, from a MySQL to a Derby, and want to know if everything was preserved in the conversion and what changes were made to table structure.

Thank you!

Ofer